# strange symbols in modal instead of content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

we created a website where we want to show some examples of our cards as thumbnails, but when you click on it a larger picture should be displayed in a modal window. Now locally (windows machine) it works perfect, but once hosted (linux machine) the whole content (title, markup, picture, buttons) of the modal are displayed as a set of strange symbols.

The code of the modal:

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <a href="images/JUNO-FOTO-MW.png" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalJUNO">
    <img src="images/JUNO-FOTO.gif" alt="geboortekaartje Juno" style="width:200px;height:200px">
    <p>geboortekaartje </br>Juno</p>
  </a>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="ModalJUNO" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Geboortekaartje Juno</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="images/JUNO-FOTO-MW.gif" title="geboortekaartje Juno" alt="geboortekaartje Juno wil nu eventjes niet laden" width="850" height="850">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[The result of the hosted site](http://www.ateljeeheksenfee.be/geboortekaartjesvoorbeeld.html)

[A part of the result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGWYR.png)

Since it is not only the picture but the whole modal that is displayed like this, it does not seems like it is an encoding problem.

Any help is greatlty appreciated!

Comment: Looking at the network tab of chrome, I can see that you image is not served correctly. That gibberish you see is the result returned as image from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `href` from your `<a>` tags.
I debugged bootstrap.js and found, that jQuery.load function is used to load modal's content.

Take a look at
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options

Read about `remote` option.